# how to add external jars in sql developer

Tags: java

I have written a program in which am using Commons-codec.jar file for encode and encode.
As am loading my code into sql developer using loadjava utility. Its giving me error. So please tell me how to add jars into sql developer.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the jar in classpath, in Linux export ...*.jar and in windows use System>> environment variable